# toggle an element's visibility using jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

I'm trying to show/hide an element by clicking on another. For simplicity, I am going to refer to each div as either A, B, C, or D, as labeled. An example of what I have so far can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/Yh8Ar/1/. So I have...

```
<div id="event">

    <div id="structure1">...</div>    // A
    <div class="structures">...</div> // B

    <div id="structure2">...</div>    // C
    <div class="structures">...</div> // D

    // more of these div pairs down here

</div>
```

... and I want the functionality to be such that when I click on div A, div B toggles between visible and hidden ( show()/hide() )... BUT... I also want div B, when visible, to hide whenever I click anywhere else in the window, except for clicking div B itself. The same goes for the other div pair (C,D)... click on C, D toggles and clicking anywhere on the page will hide D.

The tricky part here is if div B is displayed and I click on div C, I want div B to hide and div D to show. So, clicking anywhere on the page EXCEPT FOR on divs B,D will hide divs B,D respectfully. But I also want to be able to toggle div B by repeatedly clicking on div A as well as toggling div D by repeatedly clicking on div C. Only one div should be displayed at a time.

The jQuery I have so far, thanks to Nick Craver, is...

```
$(function() {

    $(document).click(function() {

        $('.structures').hide();
    });
    $('#fraction').click(function(event) {

        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
    $('.structures').click(function(event) {

        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

... but I can't figure out how to distinguish between the div pairs, meaning, I can't figure out how to hide div B and show div D when clicking on div C. Here's an example of how it works now and all the appropriate code: http://jsfiddle.net/Yh8Ar/1/

Thanks,
Hristo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine your handlers but you need to add one as well, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).click(function() {
    $('#structures').hide();
  });
  $('#structure').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#structures').show();
  });
  $('#structures').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

This *also* stops the event propagation when clicking inside the `#structures` div itself (as well as the click handler already stopping the hide from the button itself), [you can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5NBB3/).

If you want to have the button be a toggle instead, change [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: Nick... this looks good, but there is a piece missing. I would like the first div to act as a toggle... so clicking on it once will show the second div, clicking on it again will hide the second div. But I want to preserve the ability to hide the second div when clicking anywhere else on the page.

Comment: @Hristo - see the bottom of the answer :) It looks like this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5NBB3/1/

Comment: Got it... thanks for throwing in the last edit about `toggle()`. Thanks!

Comment: .. I have another question regarding this... suppose I had many of these `<div>` pairs. Now I want to extend the hiding to consider other pairs, so that when one pair shows a div, another pair would close it to display its own div. How would extend this hiding?

Comment: @Hristo - I would instead using classes, then do `$(this).next().toggle();` instead, so it's toggling the neighbor element.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things:

It might be useful to group your related divs into a container:

```
<div id="container-1" class="container">
  <div class="structure_handle">...</div>   // A
  <div class="structure_content">...</div>  // B
</div>

<div id="container-2" class="container">
  <div class="structure_handle">...</div>   // C
  <div class="structure_content">...</div>  // D
</div>
```

This way you keep the unique things unique (with an `id`) and the general things general (with a `class`). This will help you with your jQuery events. This is a quick example (untested):

```
$(function() {
   $(document).click(function() {
      $('.structure_content').hide(); // hide everything
   });
   $('.container .structure_content').click(function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation(); // don't bubble up clicks
   });
   $('.container .structure_handle').click(function() {
      $('.structure_content').hide(); // hide all other content first
      $(this).siblings('.structure_content').show(); // show only this one
   });
});
```

The `.siblings` call is why it's useful to group your divs since it limits the search space to just the grouped content.

Really though, it would probably be much cleaner to use custom events instead of trying to fit everything in to the standard click handler for this. Check out the [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) jQuery docs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You make some great points! I'm not sure what the `.siblings()` call does, I'll have to read up on that, but for now I figured it out. If you're interested in seeing what I came up with, let me know.